# How does it work when there are multiple users accessing a React web app?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React.js and new to web programming. All along when doing my own projects it's only for my own use, and hosted on localhost:3000. (i.e. one user).

I have a question about multiple users which I don't know if it's specific to React or just general web programming, but I can't seem to find it online, as perhaps it's too basic? And sorry if it's a very basic question. I will have to make an app for internal use for a team of less than 10 people soon, and it will be hosted on a local server accessible by this team.

Would the code be any different in terms of how I write this app? (say, it's just a todo list where users are able to add and remove items)
Specifically, how do states work when there are more than one user? Are they stored on the user's local device?
If one user clicks a button and sets some state from true to false for example, does it re-render for the other users too? Or do all users get their own instance of the app?

I would also appreciate it if you would know what kind of resources I should look at for this question, as I would like to read more in-depth about it.

Answer (score 0):

well, all the apps run on each user own machine independently. State, actions and all other(whole app) are happening only one user own machine. So there is no interaction if I may say so out of the box between different machines(users). You may achieve that with help of some sockets connections( for example instant chat)